# Python extract msg library: 'gbk' codec can't decode bytes: illegal multibyte sequence

Tags: python-2.7

**Bug Details**

- Using latest supported version of extract_msg. (extract_msg-0.23.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl)
- python version: Python 2.7 / Python 3.8

**Description**
I have an app which extract the email files. If the email file contains gbk codec (Chinese characters), the module method Message(path to file) throws an exception.

**Code snippet**

```
from extract_msg import Message
try:
     msg = Message(vault_path)
except Exception as e:
     return action_result.set_status(APP_ERROR, "Failed to parse message. Error: {0}".format(str(e)))
```

**The error message from library call**

**"message":"Failed to parse message. Error: 'gbk' codec can't decode bytes in position 34-35: illegal multibyte sequence"**

**Traceback:**

```
File "/opt/folder/dependencies/extract_msg/message.py", line 95, in __init__#012    self.body#012  
File "/opt/folder/dependencies/extract_msg/message.py", line 460, in body#012    self._body = self._getStringStream('__substg1.0_1000')#012 
File "/opt/folder/dependencies/extract_msg/message.py", line 166, in _getStringStream#012    return None if tmp is None else
tmp.decode(self.stringEncoding)#012UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode bytes in position 34-35: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I am not allowed to share the .msg file. The file has gbk codec (Chinese characters)

Comment: If you remove the `try...except` then you'll have a traceback you can show us.

Comment: Hey @JustinEzequiel, I just updated the question with the Traceback.